# Design - How to store a list of languages the user speaks, which will be modified and displayed?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, nosql

I would think you would do something like this:

```
speaks: {
  English: true,
  Chinese: true,
  Spanish: false,
}
```

Because a user would be able to pick multiple languages and this seems natural to a UI where they can be toggled:

```
[✓] English
[✓] Chinese
[x] Spanish
```

Then to display them you'd probably do something like

```
Object.keys(_.pickBy(speaks, _.identity))
```

The issue here is that if you had a bunch of languages (or any data that has many keys), you'd be storing a bunch of extra useless keys if they were false.

Then there's this:

```
speaks: [English, Chinese]
```

Which seems more useful for display, but not modification where you'd have to convert this into a multi-select, and do more work than just toggling state true/false (I use React so immutable slice & concat for removes, etc), then you'd have to convert your form state back into an array before saving.

How would it look in your MongoDB? I also included the graphql tag because the first way would involve defining an extra Type for the nested object, and an Input type to make changes, whereas the later would just be [String].

What do people tend to do for data like this?

Comment: What if you had 100 languages, would you store false for all the ones you can't speak? That doesn't make sense, the second option makes more sense. You can just overwrite the whole array with the languages you can speak.

Comment: For a small selection out of a large number of options, I'd either go for the array approach, or for terse storage of the flags (i.e. save only the ones, that are true, omit the false ones.) The rest depends on the capabilities of your javascript/reactjs/graphql which, alas, I don't know anything about.